# django: disable tinymce for one certain field

Tags: python, django, tinymce, field

I have a lot of models with tinymce(django-tinymce) enabled by default for TextFields and this is ok.
But for one field I don't want to apply tinymce widget (in admin interface).
Please tell me how do I implement that?

```
    class Page(models.Model):
        one = models.TextField()
        two = models.TextField()
        three = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, In your `TinyMCE.init()`, you would do:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor"
});
```

and add the class `mceNoEditor` to the textarea you want to disable tinymce on.

Here is the [relevant documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:editor_deselector)

In your example, if you want to disable it on `three`,

```
three = models.TextField(widget=form.Textarea(attrs={"class": "mceNoEditor"}))
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the point. Just added:  

        from django import forms  

        class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):  
            three = forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "mceNoEditor"})  

       class PageAdmin(TinyMCEAdmin):  
            model = Page  
            form = PageForm

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the tinymce settings are properly configure.

```
tinymce.init({
         editor_deselector : /(highlight|disablemce)/
 })
```

in my case "**editor_deselector**" has the above option.

Using admin forms to disable the tinymce option for a particular textField.
First you need to import:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django.db import models
```

and then

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
         model:MyModel
   three = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':5, 'cols':80, 'style':"width: 610px;","class": "disablemce"}))

class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
   model: MyModel
   form: MyForm
```

If you want to resize your textArea field then you simply add the **'rows':5, 'cols':80,** in your attrs options, also you want to add the width then adjust **'style':"width: 610px;"** in your attrs options.